# App not deploying in AVD via Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

Firstly, thanks for any help anyone can offer me with my foray into Android app development. I've been a Java developer for many years although I've been in management circles in recent years so a little rusty.

I've got Eclipse (Indigo) installed and I've used Eclipse extensively in the past so nothing too new to me there. I've installed the Android SDK and all the associated packages via the SDK Manager. All the icons have appeared in Eclipse and I can start an Android Project so it all looks good. I've created two AVDs - one 4.0 and another 2.1.

The trouble I'm having is getting my app (ANY app) to run in the AVD. I've followed a number of tutorials on how to do this and they are all very similar. I create a Run Configuration naming my Project and the default activity (created at the same time I created the Project) and associated it with one of the AVD (appropriate to the Project version.)

The AVD starts and eventually I get the full Android home screen, as expected, but that's it. Nothing else. I've watched a video on YouTube showing what should happen and my console output isn't the same. I don't get the bit about installing the apk.

This is the console output:

```
[2012-05-08 11:05:49 - MyFirstDroid] ------------------------------
[2012-05-08 11:05:49 - MyFirstDroid] Android Launch!
[2012-05-08 11:05:49 - MyFirstDroid] adb is running normally.
[2012-05-08 11:05:49 - MyFirstDroid] Performing com.burmania.MyFirstDroidActivity activity launch
[2012-05-08 11:05:50 - MyFirstDroid] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'API7_AVD' is not available. Launching new emulator.
[2012-05-08 11:05:50 - MyFirstDroid] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'API7_AVD
```

I've left the AVD for a number of HOURS as I've read that it can sometimes take a fair while to launch but after five hours nothing has changed.

Can anyone help me with this or point me in the right direction?

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: are you using google api for project?

Comment: Try running the AVD first, after that deploy your app.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the AVD through AVD Manager (AndroidInstallDir/AVD Manager.exe)?

If you run the AVD from there, and then use eclpise with the running AVD, it may work for you.

Comment: I've tried pretty much everything. I've run the AVD through the AVD manager and then trying running the project from Eclipse but it spawns another AVD warning that 'changes will not be persisted' because the image files are already in use (from the version run by AVD manager.)

Answer (score -1):

Found the same issue, after installing eclipse 3.7.2, android adt 21.0.0 on windows 7. 
It might be that the chosen AVD should also have an API that corresponds to the minimum chosen SDK version, otherwise if the API of the AVD is higher than that,
the also started or already running AVD is not accepted, what in fact is logical, but not clearly mentioned in the logs. 
Taking care of this solved the problem that i had. Hope this does it..